# odoo gives parse error on using email.template while creating email template

Tags: xml, email, odoo-9, email-templates

I would like to create email template in odoo. My code is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>    
      <record id="room_request_approval" model="email.template">
            <field name="name">Approval Notification</field>
            <field name="email_from">${object.users_company.email}</field>
            <field name="subject">Room request approved</field>
            <field name="email_to" >${object.assignee.email}</field>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_request_room"/>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Room Request Approved</title>
                        <style> 
                            span.oe_mail_footer_access {
                                display:block;    
                                text-align:center;
                                color:grey;                                
                            }
                        </style>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                       <p>Hiii</p>
                    </body>
                </html>
                ]]>
            </field>
        </record>
```

It is giving error as follows, ParseError: "email.template" while parsing file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if the problem is inside the `body_html` field? Try with something simpler, like the following, and also add *safe* to the emails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>    
      <record id="room_request_approval" model="email.template">
            <field name="name">Approval Notification</field>
            <field name="email_from">${(object.users_company.email or '')|safe}</field>
            <field name="subject">Room request approved</field>
            <field name="email_to" >${(object.assignee.email or '')|safe}</field>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_request_room"/>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
<p>Hello!</p>]]></field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

I guess your model is named `request.room` and it has two `Many2one` fields named `users_company` and `assignee`, hasn't it?

And in Python code, you should have something like this to send the mail:

```
request_room_recordset = self.env['request.room'].search(
    whatever_domain).ensure_one()
et_pool = self.pool.get('email.template')
mail_sent = et_pool.send_mail(
    self.env.cr, 1, template.id, request_room_recordset.id,
    force_send=True, context=self.env.context)
```

Comment: I am trying to create email template in xml. but i am not able to create email template. It says error in email.template

Comment: Try with the XML code I gave you above and check if that works. If it does, the problem must be the content of your `body_html` field.

Comment: Still i am getting error like.....  ParseError: "email.template" while parsing file
<record id="case_creation_invitation" model="email.template">
            <field name="name">Case information</field>
            <field name="email_from">someid</field>
   <field name="subject">New case qrqefe created</field>
   <field name="email_to">someid</field>
   <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
   <field name="model_id" ref="model_customer_service_management"/>
   <field name="body_html">&lt;p&gt; Hello! &lt;/p&gt;</field>
        </record>

Comment: But then, the error is not in the email template you have posted, but in other email template whose `id` is *case_creation_invitation*. And it seems that `someid` in email fields is one of the possible causes. Post that template. Did you create it too?

Comment: i have no email template other than this. I am not using this id anywhwere.

Comment: According to the error message you have posted me above, it is sure that there is a XML record with `id` *case_creation_invitation* which is raising the error. Try to look for it with this expression in console (if you are using a Linux distro): `grep -nrsH "id=.case_creation_invitation." /* --include="*.xml"`. After a while, this will return you the file which contains this code.

Comment: I am sorry, i didnt checked existence of that id. Instead i changed the id, then also it is showing error

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'email_template' dependency in your **openerp**.py. Hope it works.